# How to find list of supported smileys short cut in browsers?

Tags: jquery, html, emoticons

I've specified list of smileys text when typed in the textarea will fetch related icon from specified folder thus display as smiley on browsers without reloading:

```
var icons = {
            ':-)' : 'smile',
            ':)'  : 'smile',
            ':('  : 'sad',
            ':D'  : 'laugh',
            ':=D' : 'laugh',
            ':-D' : 'laugh',
            '8=)' : 'cool',
            '8-)' : 'cool',
            'B=)' : 'cool',
            ';)'  : 'wink',
            ';-)' : 'wink',
            ';=)' : 'wink',
            ':o'  : 'surprised',
            ':=o' : 'surprised',
            ':-o' : 'surprised',                
            ';('  : 'crying',
            ';-(' : 'crying',
            ';=(' : 'crying',           
            '(:|' : 'sweating',
            ':|'  : 'speechless',
            ':=|' : 'speechless',
            ':-|' : 'speechless',
            ':*'  : 'kiss',
            ':=*' : 'kiss',
            ':-*' : 'kiss',
            ':P'  : 'cheeky',
            ':=P' : 'cheeky',
            ':-P' : 'cheeky',
            ':p'  : 'cheeky', 
            ':$'  : 'blush',
            ':-$' : 'blush',
            ':^)' : 'wondering',
            '|-)' : 'sleepy',
            'I-)' : 'sleepy',
            'I=)' : 'sleepy',
            '|('  : 'dull',
            '|-(' : 'dull',
            '|=(' : 'dull',
            ']:)' : 'evilgrin',
            '>:)' : 'evilgrin',             
            ':&'  : 'puke',
            ':-&' : 'puke',
            ':=&' : 'puke',
            ':-@' : 'angry', 
            'x('  : 'angry',
            'x-(' : 'angry',
            'x=(' : 'angry',
            'X('  : 'angry',            
            '8-|' : 'nerd',
            'B-|' : 'nerd',
            '8|'  : 'nerd',
            'B|'  : 'nerd'
        };
```

I've found that in the list above there're some not supported by browsers like chrome and firefox. Namely, :`*:& x( 8-|`
How do I find our which browsers supports which shortcuts?

> I know there's no automatic substitution for emo in browsers. I've a
>   simple function that gets the text typed in the textarea, detects
>   characters specified in the icons object above then replaces them with
>   proper icons I have in a folder.
>
> What I'm concerned is, when I refresh the page, the emoji characters I
>   entered earlier are not converted to proper emoji but displays as
>   text. I need to know list of characters for emojis supported by
>   browsers so that I can create icons with that characters.

**This is how the conversion done**

```
$('[data-ckit-footer]').off('keypress.compose').on('keypress.compose', '[data-ckit-composer-textarea]', function(event) {

    replyMessage = true;
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    var composer = $('[data-ckit-composer-textarea]');
    var message = $.trim(composer.val());

    if (keycode == '13' && !event.shiftKey) {
        //prevent moving to next line
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!message) {

            $('[data-show-warning-empty]')
            .css({
                'background-color': '#fcf0ed',
                'color': '#f2575b',
                'padding': '10px'
            })
            .html('Please type a message');
            return;
        }

        //get from emoticon library
        var progressiveText = $('[data-ckit-composer-textarea]').emoticons();
        $('[data-body]').find('[data-chat]').html(progressiveText); 
    }
});
```

**This is the library:**

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.emoticons = function(options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            folder: "/plugins/system/conversekit/assets/images/icons/",
            img_ext: "png"
        }, options );

        var text = this.val();
        var folder = settings.folder;
        var img_ext = settings.img_ext;
        var icons = {
            ':-)' : 'smile',
            ':)'  : 'smile',
            ':('  : 'sad',
            ':D'  : 'laugh',
            ':=D' : 'laugh',
            ':-D' : 'laugh',
            '8=)' : 'cool',
            '8-)' : 'cool',
            'B=)' : 'cool',
            ';)'  : 'wink',
            ';-)' : 'wink',
            ';=)' : 'wink',
            ':o'  : 'surprised',
            ':=o' : 'surprised',
            ':-o' : 'surprised',                
            ';('  : 'crying',
            ';-(' : 'crying',
            ';=(' : 'crying',           
            '(:|' : 'sweating',
            ':|'  : 'speechless',
            ':=|' : 'speechless',
            ':-|' : 'speechless',
            ':*'  : 'kiss',
            ':=*' : 'kiss',
            ':-*' : 'kiss',
            ':P'  : 'cheeky',
            ':=P' : 'cheeky',
            ':-P' : 'cheeky',
            ':p'  : 'cheeky', 
            ':$'  : 'blush',
            ':-$' : 'blush',
            ':^)' : 'wondering',
            '|-)' : 'sleepy',
            'I-)' : 'sleepy',
            'I=)' : 'sleepy',
            '|('  : 'dull',
            '|-(' : 'dull',
            '|=(' : 'dull',
            ']:)' : 'evilgrin',
            '>:)' : 'evilgrin',             
            ':&'  : 'puke',
            ':-&' : 'puke',
            ':=&' : 'puke',
            ':-@' : 'angry', 
            'x('  : 'angry',
            'x-(' : 'angry',
            'x=(' : 'angry',
            'X('  : 'angry',            
            '8-|' : 'nerd',
            'B-|' : 'nerd',
            '8|'  : 'nerd',
            'B|'  : 'nerd'
        };  

        return text.replace(/[:;8B>^*@$&I\]|\-(=o)pPxXD]+/g, function (match) {
            return typeof icons[match] != 'undefined' ? '<span class="emoticons"><img src="'+folder+'/'+icons[match]+'.'+img_ext+'"/></span>' : match;
        }); 


    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: I'm confused. To the best of my knowledge, no web browsers implement any kind of automatic emoticon substitutions, so it doesn't make sense to talk about ones that are "not supported by some browsers". Can you please explain exactly what you're referring to, and include all relevant code in your question?

Comment: @duskwuff, please refer highlighted part in my edited post above.

Comment: Where's the conversion code? None of this really makes much sense without a [mcve]

Comment: If your Javascript code is handling the replacement, **we need to see that code**.

Comment: @duskwuff, look at my code above..hope its enough